# STM32F4 Delay after button press in EXTI0

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm trying to stop the user from pressing the button for 1 second if it has already been pressed. Can this be done without using the superloop in main.c?
My EXTI0 is in stm32f4xx_it.

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 0 */
    if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_0))
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler();
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        } 
        else
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Comment: Disable IRQ after user event and enable it after 1 second by timer.

Comment: How can you disable the IRQ?

Comment: I don't know how it disable in HAL, but through periferal registers access it's very simple: `EXTI->IMR |= EXTI_IMR_MR0` - enable interrupt at EXTI line 0, `EXTI->IMR &= (uint32_t)~EXTI_IMR_MR0` - disable.

Answer (score 0):

If the user press a button you can get the syste time and save it inside a variable. if the user press again, you can check, if enough time has passed. The example is just for show the mechanism and is just one possibility to solve your problem.

```
 int nLastPress = 0;
 void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
 {
      if(nLastPress + 1 < SYSTEM_TIME_IN_SECONDS)
      {
         // do your stuff
         nLastPress = SYSTEM_TIME_IN_SECONDS;
      }
      else
      {
          // don't handle user input
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, how do i get the system time, and will this method stop the button from bouncing and producing multiple printfs?

Comment: You can get the system tim with `clock()`. The unit depends on your clockspeed, you have to convert it to seconds. It prevents your buttons from bouncing in software. But a hardware anti ouncing is always better. Where do you print something?

Comment: I'm printing to a debug window and which uses TIM11 to show the temperature. How would i do a hardware anti bouncing?

Comment: No, a hardware "anti bouncing" is not "always better" - in fact it is rather rarely used.  Unless there's a reason you *cannot* use software debouncing (which is rare, if the source of legitimate events is a human and the consumer of them is software) the cost-per-unit of doing so is free, while doing it in hardware is not, especially if you have to go back and rework or revise the boards to add it.  If you expect a lot of bounces, disabling the interrupt for a window will reduce software load, but even having the ISR trigger and reject bounces within a time window may work in some cases.